# Do generic smooth functions have no degenerate points?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request

In this question, $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.

Let $M$ be a compact $D$-dimensional $C^\infty$-smooth manifold, and fix a finite atlas $\,\mathcal{U}=\{\phi_j \,\colon U_j \to \mathbb{R}^D\}_{j=1,\ldots,n}$ of $C^\infty$ charts on $M$. Let $A=\{\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1,\ldots,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{D+1}\}$ be a set of $D+1$ distinct multi-indices $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_i \in \mathbb{N}^D$, and let $K=\max\{\|\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\|_1,\ldots,\|\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{D+1}\|_1\}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all $C^\infty$ functions $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for every chart $\,\phi_j \, \colon U_j \to \mathbb{R}^D$ in $\,\mathcal{U}$, for each $\mathbf{x} \in \phi_j(U_j)$, at least one of the multi-indices $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_i \in A$ has $\partial_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{i\!}}(f \circ \phi_j^{-1})(\mathbf{x}) \neq 0$.

> Is it the case that for every $k \in \{K,K+1,\ldots\} \cup \{\infty\}$, $\mathcal{F}$ is dense in $C^k(M,\mathbb{R})$?

My intuition is that the answer is *yes*, and furthermore that this result – or something similar – should be a well-known result (probably with a name), or should at least exist in some textbook.

> Is there a reference for this result, or a name for this result?

Comment: It may matter what norm the $C^k(M,\mathbb{R})$ are equipped with.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh I didn't know there's any ambiguity as to which norm I would be referring to if I simply write $C^k(M,\mathbb{R})$. I don't know of any topologies on $C^k(M,\mathbb{R})$ other than the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but I suspect you will need to use *Morse theory*.
A Morse function is a function without degenerate critical points, where a critical point $p \in M$ has $df_p=0$ and a degenerate critical point also has the Hessian equal to zero.
Morse functions form an open, dense subset of $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$.
They appear in most textbooks on differential topology, such as Mukherjee's *Differential Topology*, Theorem 9.1.3.